# how do I access data in a nested json data

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way to access data from a nested json file? I created a json file with one parent object, and three children in side the parent. What I'm trying to achieve is that I want to access the data inside the children. I can display all the data in the json file using postman with the address localhost:3030/parent. If I try to access the data in the any of the children I get an empty object.The address  localhost:3030/parent/child/data is giving me empty object. So is there a way to achieve this. Here is my json file

```
 [
    {
        "medias":[
            {
                "Featured": [
                    {
                    "id": "1",
                    "title": "featured1",
                    "thumbUrl": "../assets/images/Featured/52.png"
                    },
                    {
                    "id": "2",
                    "title": "featured2",
                    "thumbUrl": "../assets/images/Featured/debas-film-us1.png"
                    },
                    {
                    "id": "3",
                    "title": "featured3",
                    "thumbUrl": "../assets/images/Featured/1964.png"
                    },
                    {
                    "id": "4",
                    "title": "featured4": "../assets/images/Featured/102.png"
                    },
                    {
                    "id": "5",
                    "title": "featured5",
                    "thumbUrl": "../assets/images/Featured/32.png"
                    },
                    {
                    "id": 20,
                    "title": "featured6"
                    }
                ],
                "New": [
                    {
                    "id": "6",
                    "title": "new1",
                    "thumbUrl": "../assets/images/New/54.png"
                    },
                    {
                    "id": "7",
                    "title": "new2",
                    "thumbUrl": "../assets/images/New/74.png"
                    },
                    {
                    "id": "8",
                    "title": "new3",
                    "thumbUrl": "../assets/images/New/64.png"
                    },
                    {
                    "id": "9",
                    "title": "new4",
                    "thumbUrl": "../assets/images/New/44.png"
                    },
                    {
                    "id": "10",
                    "title": "new5",
                    "thumbUrl": "../assets/images/New_Movies/34.png"
                    }
                    
                ],
                "Seires": [
                    {
                    "id": "11",
                    "title": "series1",
                    "thumbUrl": "../pictures/Series_Movies/1963.png"
                    },
                    {
                    "id": "12",
                    "title": "series2",
                    "thumbUrl": "../pictures/Series_Movies/219.png"
                    },
                    {
                    "id": "13",
                    "title": "series3",
                    "thumbUrl": "../assets/images/Series/31.png"
                    },
                    {
                    "id": "14",
                    "title": "series4",
                    "thumbUrl": "../assets/images/Series/41.png"
                    },
                    {
                    "id": "15",
                    "title": "series5",
                    "thumbUrl": "../assets/images/Series/61.png"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
 ]
```

Comment: have you created an api for this path - localhost:3030/parent.

Comment: I am fairly new to this. I haven't created an api for the localhost:3030/parent..but I'm using json-server if that helps

Comment: as per your code, your parent is an array.

Comment: Ok..Then how do I fix that

Comment: Provide your code that trying to manipulate this object for ease of getting help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access nested values in your object, always be aware of what you are actually trying to access. As the the response you are receiving is an array, you will need to use the index of said array to traverse down to your desired data.

First step:

```
const response = [{"medias": [...]}];
```

You can access the this object by calling response[0] as it is the first object in this array that you are trying to access.

```
const responseLevelOne = response[0];
```

So currently `responseLevelOne` looks like this: `{"medias": [...]}`.
Note that the next level is not an array but an object. To drill down further, you will have to use the key of the value that you are trying to access.

```
const responseLevelTwo = responseLevelOne["medias"];
```

This will give you the following array:

```
[{"Featured": [...], "New": [...], "Seires":[...]}]
```

As you might see, this array countains a single object again. So in order to get to next level, we will have to refer to the first entry of that array again:

```
const responseLevelThree = responseLevelTwo[0];
```

I think you get the idea by now. You just have to be careful about indexing/accessing the next level correctly as it the response nests array and object in a quite complex way, which makes the whole procedure quite prone to error.

I would suggest to simply console.log your way down to the entries you are looking for.